# How do I stop a list "assigned to" person from getting email notifications?

Tags: notifications

With each item added to the list, we have two people assigned. One person is the owner of the task as a whole, the other is the owner of a subtask. After the subtask owner completes his work, he still gets alerts as the owner updates the item. How do I stop the subtask owner from getting alerts?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the alerts and create a custom designer workflow where you can have your condition as when you want the email to be triggered and to whom

Comment: We have 2010 Foundation without workflow capabilities. Is there a workaround until we upgrade SharePoint?

Comment: Even if you have foundation, you can create the designer workflows..Other workaround may be customizing of Alerts..i am unsure of it though...

Comment: I tried designer workflow this morning and I think its more effort than its worth. I think I need to determine how we can make updates without multiple alerts going to users.